# Shoplifting vs. a word for "someone who orders, eats and sneaks without paying the check"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expression-choice

***Shoplifting*** relates more to the physical possession of goods.

> A shoplifter may pretend to be a customer or buy some and steal many
>   (or vice-versa). But while at a restaurant such pretense won't work.
>   **Stealing** food too is different.

- A word for "*someone who orders, eats and sneaks without paying the check*.

I came across a french word- **Mouche**- meaning 'fly' ...but could not find a proper ***ONE WORD*** substitute.

Comment: You probably mean "*mooch*" which means to beg or contrive to be given something for free. It's not stealing though, because it's being given.

Comment: No he meant what he said. Mooch is an English word. Mooch also wouldn't apply to a dine & dasher because the restaurant would have to be knowingly giving the food away in that scenario.

Comment: Not exactly a definition, but I would call that person a "scumbag".

Comment: Sometimes, Yiddish is the only language to capture an idea!  -- gonif would do.

Comment: Jim, if you're wondering about "mouche" it's just the French word for the insect, an ordinary house-fly.  There is utterly no connection to "mooch" in English.

Comment: @Jim You must be north American! I thought your definition of 'mooch' was wrong so I looked it up - turns out it has different meanings on either side of the Atlantic (though probably related). British 'mooch' means 'to loiter in a bored or listless manner'.

Comment: @JoeBlow- Right, I understand that *mouche* is French for fly.  But why did the OP choose to include this seemingly unrelated word in the question? OP obviously thought it *was* related.  OP is obviously not French, because s/he uses the phrase "*came across a French word*" and since s/he gives the definition as "fly" and not "a person who eats and *flies away*" (for example).  Rightly or wrongly I concluded that the only thing it could have in common is a pronunciation overlap.  If you know why *mouche* is applicable to this question in a different way *je suis tout ouïe*

Comment: The formal French word for that is “grivèlerie”, never heard “mouche” in that sense.

Comment: Typing in the correct German term "Zechpreller" into a translation engine gave the result "bilk". Never heard that word being used myself. Another word is "dodger" as in "fare dodger" - which is close enough in meaning, but I've never heard of a "restaurant bill dodger".

Comment: In addition to the British meaning of _mooch_ mentioned above, _on the mooch_ in Ireland can mean playing truant from school.

Comment: Of course you can always have the case, as I have done, where you are seated, brought some bread and the menus and then walk out 35 minutes later, having eaten the bread but been unable to order from the staff. (We were followed out by the occupants of at least 6 other tables).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is known as a 
***Dine and Dash***

> A dine and dash (also referred to as "dine and ditch", "eat and run", "chew and screw" "doing a runner" or "beating the check") is a form of theft by fraud, in which a patron orders and consumes food from a restaurant or similar establishment with no intent to pay, then leaves without paying. <sub><sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dine_and_dash)</sup></sub>

Comment: I've also heard servers refer to the customers themselves (as well as the act) as *walkouts*, though this probably doesn't discriminate against non-food theft.

Comment: Ah, walkout - brilliant. That's the correct "industry term" in many/most places.

Comment: @geobits, you should make that an answer since it's the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't know about "eat and run", but I think it's brilliant.

Comment: "Eat and run" is the most common in the form of AmE I speak.

Comment: What is it called when the patron orders and consumes food with the intent to pay, but when the bill comes discovers that they are unable to?

Comment: @Michael "Dishwasher"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton anecdotally, yes, but is that what happens in real life?

Comment: +1. The teenage boys in my neighborhood referred to this activity as a  "chew & screw." My first few "dinner dates" ended that way. Oh, those were the days ...

Answer (score 13):

In a retail context you would refer to them as a "**[grazer](http://scrubs.wikia.com/wiki/My_Lunch_transcript)**".

Echoing Geobit's comment, you might consider a "[**walkout**](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/food/2013/12/suzanne_parratt_servers_being_forced_to_pay_for_walkouts_is_surprisingly.html)".

Or more prosaicly, you might simply refer to them as a "[**thief**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thief)", since that's what they are.

Answer (score 11):

A common phrase for that type of thing (at least in some areas),

is "runner", "a runner", "did a runner".

Comment: "doing a runner" was already included in Jim's answer, half an hour before yours

Comment: Ah, well done Jim !

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between stealing food and eating food and not paying for it.  The second is a subset of the first.

There are definitely terms for the act of eating at a restaurant and leaving without paying—chew and screw, dine and dash, or eat and run, for example—but I can't think of any that specifically refer to the perpetrator.

Mooch is a good start, but does not imply the illegality (since typically a mooch asks for what they don't pay for). Perhaps freeloader, parasite, or sponge, but again none of those have the implication of theft. Con artist captures the "trick" aspect of the theft, but has connotations of a hustler who convinces their victim to do something they would not ordinarily do (and waiters are always serving food).

So moving on to words describing theft: filcher might work and swindler seems apt, but neither is specific to this act.

This might be the time to make up a term: perhaps pie-jacker or sandwichbagger? ;)

Comment: I like *pie-jacker*!

Comment: You are correct, mike. I fixed the spelling.

Comment: There is a distinction between stealing food and eating and not paying for it. If someone has a restaurant meal, planning to pay, and then when the bill comes they decides to run away, they haven't stolen the food. You can't steal something that you've already digested. 

In England and Wales, until the Theft Act 1978 created the offence of 'making of without payment' they wouldn't have been guilty of any crime, although they would be in debt to the restaurant.

Comment: so you're telling me that there may be a legal distinction, but in reality it is theft.  How often does one sit down, intending to pay, and then run away before settling the bill?  Outside of 'rampaging maniac' and 'disaster' movies where there is suddenly a much more pressing concern?

Answer (score 4):

I have heard the term "check walking" or "check walker"
The idea being, they walk out without paying the check.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer could be improved with examples, for example, from published works or links to online dictionaries. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly obscure, but you can use [bilking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bilk) (Oxford Dictionaries) - withholding money unfairly. This has been fairly frequently applied to people failing to pay at resturants, e.g. "*Man who bilked El Bulli is found*".

As Richard says in his comment there is also the term from the British Theft Act, *making off without payment*.

Answer (score 1):

In the US I've heard this referred to as "choke-n-bolt".

Answer (score 1):

The closest single word (as opposed to phrase) that I know is [scarper](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scarper), although scarper may also used be generally for any hasty exit to avoid consequences.

Answer (score 1):

'dodger'--someone who resorts to dishonest tricks to avoid something unpleasant (like paying the check at a restaurant or leaving the gas station without paying after a fill-up). The Los Angeles Dodgers baseball team used to be called the Brooklyn (NYC) Dodgers, named after the 'trolley dodger'--someone who rides on the trolley and gets off without paying.

Answer (score 1):

**Bilking** used to be a famous word in our university campus for **eat and sneak** types.

Answer (score 1):

**Stiffed** as a transitive verb is to cheat someone out of money owed or not to pay someone an amount due or expected. “He stiffed me on the tip.” Encarta Dictionary North American

Answer (score -3):

The legal term is "Defrauding an Innkeeper".

Comment: In the UK, the legal definition is "making off"; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Making_off_without_payment